# show and create object from many2one relation in related model's template

Tags: django, html, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have this models design:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    ID = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    name = models.CharField(default='node', max_length=32)

class Firm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class ScheduledAction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    firm = models.ForeignKey('Firm', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    node = models.ForeignKey('Node', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

I created a form class for each model: NodeForm, FirmForm, and ScheduledActionForm. Now I want to create a template where: I can show for one Firm: the list of nodes (in a checkbox list), the list of already created scheduled actions for this firm, and a simple input area where for the selected nodes,  I create scheduled actions. So this is what I started in `planification.html`:

```
<div name="FirmName">
    {{ object }}
    <h1>Firm: {{ object.name }}</h1>
</div>
<div name="NodesOfFirm">
    {% for instance in object.node_set.all %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ instance.name }}" value="{{ instance.id }}"> {{ instance.name }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div name="planification">
    <h1>Planification</h1>

</div>
<div name="scheduledActions">
    <h1>Scheduled Actions</h1>
    {% for instance in object.scheduledaction_set.all %}
        <p>{{instance.date}} - {{ instance.node }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

in views.py:

```
def planification_view(request, id):
    obj = Firm.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, "node/planification.html", context)
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to create a scheduled action (input area in planification div). Any suggestions? Thanks.